# How to fix colors of LISA Cluster maps from Pysal

Tags: python, matplotlib, maps, gis, pysal

I am using the [LISA Cluster package](https://pysal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/pysal.viz.splot.esda.lisa_cluster.html#pysal.viz.splot.esda.lisa_cluster) from [Pysal](https://pysal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#) to create a LISA (Local Indicator of Spatial Autocorrelation) map.

As the example of the documentation shows, the color lightblue is used to identify regions classified as "Low-High"

[image]

The problem is that, when I generate a map, that does not have a region in  each of the 4 categories (HH, HL, LH, LL) the color attributed to the existent categories is changed, creating a problem to compare different maps:

[image]

In the Figure above, there is no regions classified as HL, so the color orange was atributed to LH, instead of lightblue.

How can I fix the colors, so LH will always be lightblue and so the others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should upgrade pysal. This was [a known issue](https://github.com/pysal/pysal/issues/1101), solved in pysal 2.1.0 version.